# Details about function arguments through Lua C API

Tags: lua, function-parameter, lua-api

if I call a function `foo(t[1])` through the C API, can I in any way see what table and what index is as argument, in this case `t` and `1`?

The problem at hand is a function `move_card(card, table_slots[0])` where I move a card from one slot on a game area to another one. `table_slots` can also be `hand` or `player_slots`. This can be solved using a metatable, stating the name of the table being accessed. But the index is impossible to solve, or is it? `table_slots[0]` can be a `card` table, or an `overlay` or `stack` (arrays of cards), or `nil` if it's empty, as could `player_slots`. But what I need to know is in fact if it's from a `table_slots` or `player_slots`.

Could I hack some code analysis? Like, get the line where the function call is made, and then grep the index through a regexp? I could send `table_slots[0]` as a string, also, like `move_card(card, "table_slot[0]")`. Not as elegant, but still working.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once a value reaches a function, be it C or Lua, its origins are lost.

On the other hand, when an error occurs in Lua, the runtime system tries quite a bit to reconstruct the origin of the relevant values, but it does not always succeeds.